# Jquery dynamic text effect / class problem

Tags: jquery, dynamic-data

I have a html file containing a table with some rows n columns. each row contain a button, which has some functions. First, it has to submit the data in a row to a php file, which is not printing anything. Then the button have to change its text and text in column 5 of its corresponding row. The change text effect of button is working well. But the change text effect of column 5 is buggy. Only the text of column5 in first row is changing, no matter which button you click.. Can anyone fix the problem for me??

Thanks in advance :)

blasteralfred

```
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<style>  
.style1 {  
    background-color: #c3d9ff;  
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;  
}  
.style2 {  
    text-align: center;  
    font-weight: bold;  
}  
.style3 {  
    background-color: #FFFFFF;  
    font-family:arial,sans-serif;  
    text-align: center;  
    font-weight: bold;  
}  
body {  
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
font-size:15px;  
background-color: ;  
}  
.delete_button {  
font-weight:bold;  
float:right;  
}  
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function()  
{  
    $(".delete_button").click(function()  
    {  
    var id = $(this).attr("id");  
    var dataString = 'id='+ id ;  
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();  
    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",  
        url: "del.php",  
        data: dataString,  
        cache: false,  
        success: function()  
        {  
            if(id % 2)  
            {  
                parent.fadeOut('fast', function() {$(this).fadeOut();$(this).fadeIn();});  
            }  
            else  
            {  
                parent.fadeOut('fast', function()   {$(this).fadeOut();$(this).fadeIn();});  
            }  
        }  
    });  
    return false;  
    }  
);});  
$(document).ready(function() {  
  $('.delete_button').click(function() {  
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Inactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Inactivate');  
    $("#clickme2").text($("#clickme2").text() == 'Inactive' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive');  
    return false;  
});  
});  
</script>
</head>  
<body>  
<table style="width: 90%" align="center" class="style1">
<tr>  
        <td colspan="7" class="style2">MANAGER</td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">column1</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">column2</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">column3</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">column4</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">column5</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 144px">column6</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="">Action</td>  
    </tr>  
        <tr>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg1</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg2</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg3</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg4</td>  
        <td div id="clickme2" class="style3" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 144px">msg6</td>  
        <td  style="width: ">  
            <button class="delete_button" style="width:80px;height:">Activate</button>  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg1</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg2</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg3</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg4</td>  
        <td div id="clickme2" class="style3" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 144px">msg6</td>  
        <td  style="width: ">  
            <button class="delete_button" style="width:80px;height:">Activate</button>  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg1</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg2</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg3</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg4</td>  
        <td div id="clickme2" class="style3" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 144px">msg6</td>  
        <td  style="width: ">  
            <button class="delete_button" style="width:80px;height:">Activate</button>  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg1</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg2</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg3</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg4</td>  
        <td div id="clickme2" class="style3" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 144px">msg6</td>  
        <td  style="width: ">  
            <button class="delete_button" style="width:80px;height:">Activate</button>  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg1</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg2</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg3</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg4</td>  
        <td div id="clickme2" class="style3" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 144px">msg6</td>  
        <td  style="width: ">  
            <button class="delete_button" style="width:80px;height:">Activate</button>  
        </td>  
    </tr>  
    <tr>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg1</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg2</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg3</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 139px">msg4</td>  
        <td div id="clickme2" class="style3" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>  
        <td class="style3" style="width: 144px">msg6</td>  
        <td  style="width: ">  
            <button class="delete_button" style="width:80px;height:">Activate</button>  
        </td>  
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an id multiple times (*this is invalid, and not allowed in the HTML specs*). When you target this you always get the first one only.

Use the `clickme2` as a class instead of an id and target it from the click handler like this

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.clickme2').text(...);
```

Also, remove the ***div*** attribute from the `td` tags as that does not exists either.

---

Example at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/23KEW/

Comment: @blasteralfred, example works fine. (*the ajax is not working on the example as it is not running from your server..*)

Comment: See gaby, the text in column 5 is not changing in your example.. i tried from your link and i ran it in my localhost.. ajax works fine .. no prob..

Comment: @blasteralfred, try http://www.jsfiddle.net/23KEW/1/ I was using the `console.log` command for debugging, and if you do not have a debugger enabled it failed at that point. (*it has been commented out now*)

Answer (score 1):

you have got error in you javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.delete_button').click(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Inactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Inactivate');
    $("#clickme2").text($("#clickme2").text() == 'Inactive' ? 'Active' : 'Inactive');/*you are giving same id to all rows in 5 th column and selecting it*/
    return false;
    });
});
```

You should remove id from here

```
 <td div id="clickme2" class="style3" style="width: 139px">Inactive</td>
```

and change your javascript to

then in youjavascript

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$('.delete_button').click(function() {
    $(this).text($(this).text() == 'Inactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Inactivate');
        $(this).closest("td").prev().prev().text($(this).text() == 'Inactivate' ? 'Activate' : 'Inactivate');
    return false;
    });
});
```

but i am not sure about ajax request

Comment: Thanks.. But the data in column 5 is "Active" and "Inactive", not "Activate" and "Inactivate".. They belong to buttons.. can you correct the suggestion for me??